# Get indexposition from nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, nested

I have a nested list

```
nested_list = [["cats", "dogs", "cars"], ["dogs", "green", ", "red"], ["cars", "black", "purple"]]
```

and I need to get each index position [1] in the range of the  nested_list
so I get the resulting list `["cats", "dogs", "cars"]`

Comment: Do you just want `nested_list[0]`? The exact list you chose makes it hard to tell what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to build a resulting list from the desired index positions.

```
result = [sublist[0] for sublist in nested_list]
```

Btw, python indexing starts with 0.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do that is using list comprehension in Python.

```
>>> nested_list = [["cats", "dogs", "cars"], ["dogs", "green", "", "red"], ["cars", "black", "purple"]]
>>> res = [l[0] for l in nested_list]
 ['cats', 'dogs', 'cars']
```

By the way, you say you want to get each element of position 1, however in your example you are getting position 0, Python starts counting at position 0